# Automating alignment sheet band-data on map with ArcMap and ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

[image]

Anyone have some logic or code samples to automate creating band data for alignment/integrity pipeline sheets showing various point/polyline events along the pipe in configurable way or otherwise ArcMap 10.0 and Arcpy?  Even logic or code in ArcObjects would be helpful.

I've seen some applications use polygons and polylines to build the border and band elements like tick marks and the pipeline representation in the band.  It seems like final printed sheet dimension output would need to be a configurable variable.  What else?

Comment: Any chance you could provide a url that has a downloadable sample alignment sheet pdf illustrating what you describe?

Comment: http://bit.ly/GArLEc I did a quick search on google images for 'alignment sheet'.  Having the main map to show the target linear feature and then having different "bands" of various events (linear/point).  If the target linear feature starts at m-value 100ft then the event band would start at 100ft whether it had events there or not.  Maybe potholes on a road go every 1000ft, so if the target linear feature (road layer) was broken up in 500ft segments for each page then potholes band would be sparsely populated.  Thanks.

Comment: @Justin Did end up figuring out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Data Driven Pages with a Strip Map Index for which a good starting point is in the [ArcGIS 10.0 Online Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000006000000) (see the second example that uses the Nile River).

Comment: This looks to do the work of building the individual map pages.  More sophisticated than just building grids because it gives more relevant info like dataframe rotation.  Which is cool.  My question though is after having these pages partioned out, how to create detail bands of various event data.  Similar to how alignment sheets work.

Comment: This sounds more like linear referencing (aka dynamic segmentation).  To find out what alignment sheets are I just did some quick research to find diagrams at http://www.newcenturysoftware.com/products/sheetcutter.html and http://thiiink.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/python-based-alignment-sheet-generator/ and http://site.ge-energy.com/businesses/ge_oilandgas/en/prod_serv/serv/pipeline/en/downloads/GE_PII_SheetGen_FS_NA_091208-PRESS.pdf - it looks like it may be well on the way to being a crowded solution space.

Comment: As GIS Developers go rogue!  I don't see the dynamic segmentation..but linear referencing a sure bet.  I am trying to boil it down to getting the size of the map page in ArcMap to know how many units the band will be and trying to sync that with the map showing the pipeline just in case there is some rubberbanding needed to have the events in the band sync right with their linear reference to the polyline upon which they hang like a skeleton.