# Does QGIS feature a tool like ArcGIS Data Driven Pages?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

Has QGIS progressed to the point of having a Data Driven Pages type tool set yet?
Or perhaps something similar to the old DS MapBook pre arcgis 10?

Answer (score 10):

That feature is called **Atlas** in QGIS and you'll find it as part of the Print Composer.
[It's described in the user manual](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#atlas-generation).

[image]

Comment: Thanks underdark. I have explored this tool a bit, does it produce any vector outputs? Also, I have not be able to find any "strip map" functionally similar to arcgis ddp, just the grid map. We are looking to produce a series of page polygons based on a contiguous polyline aka "strip map".

Comment: @sirgeo Can you provide an example of "strip map". I'm not familiar with what that is.

Comment: Alignment Sheets use the strip map tools  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00sr/GUID-ACDEB485-5AA3-41BA-BAF8-8E7A3627A52D-web.png   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000006000000   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21816/solution-to-automate-alignment-sheet-band-data-on-map-with-arcmap-10-0-and-arcpy

Comment: @sirgeo ah, so the point is the rotation?

Comment: yes, rotation and having vector output capabilities... does this seem like something QGIS can presently do? If not, when do you think it might be added?

Comment: SVG output from print composer has some issues that go back to the underlying Qt library. There is a plugin that promises better SVG output but I have not tried it. Concerning rotation, I don't think that will be added without funding from an interested party.