# Algorithm to optimally split a map comprising many separate areas into panels for printing

Tags: printing, mapping

I have a map of set of land parcels (polygons) that need to inserted into a document. Some of these polygons are contiguous, but some can be scattered randomly. The area is typically too large for a one page map. So the map must be divided into several tiles/panels. Each tile/panel is of fixed scale and size, but the corner coordinate doesn't have to be on a fixed grid.

A naive approach is to use a regular grid and printing any tile that touches one of the polygons. However this leads to really sub-optimal results. For example if a polygon contains a grid corner you have 4 tiles when one tile could do the job.

The following image illustrates the problem: 4 tiles/panels should be sufficient to print this map, but the naive approach doubles that to 8. This will be fun algorithm figure out, but I'm sure this problem has been solved before. Any pointers (or even keywords to use in a search) would be helpful.

I'm writing custom non-interactive/batch oriented software (in Java), so algorithms, papers or libraries is what I'm most interested in. However pointers to software products (particularly if open source) might be helpful also.

[image: example of poor division of map into tiles for printing]

Comment: What software are you using? If you have ArcMap look at Data Driven Pages https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003m000000 , this is *exactly* what this utility was designed for. If you have QGIS look up Atlas https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77737/does-qgis-feature-a-tool-like-arcgis-data-driven-pages , have a read of the appropriate page for your software and see if you can implement DDP/Atlas for your data.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm writing my own software. So either an algorithm or a code library (ideally Java) is what I'm looking for.

Comment: actually that pointer to Atlas could be very useful: it doesn't solve the immediate problem (since I need to embed it into a very batch/non-interactive oriented software) but it looks like it's a good starting point for more research. Thanks!

Comment: Your're welcome. Atlas should be open source so you could download and peruse it for ideas, provided the source code is in a language you can understand well enough.