# Linear referenced data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

I am trying to create a form of data driven page that incorporates linear referencing  very similar to the ["Linear referencing scenarios" example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Linear_referencing_scenarios/003900000004000000/):

[image]

I have a map that I will display on each page that shows a long polygon of a construction section for a pipeline. However, I just want the map to show the base imagery layer and the polygon.

The linear referenced data needs to be displayed outside the map area in an abstract manner much the same as the example, almost like a table underneath the map. If one were to take a straight edge and draw a vertical line on the page through the table, one would be able to determine each of the variables in question. (I keep thinking of the London Underground example, considering how the diagram shows a straight horizontal line where in reality it twists and turns)

I have eleven such routes (variables) to display for each page which shows about 8 km of the pipeline. (in the example, it would be accidents, lanes, material, speed, and quality). Seven of my routes are line referenced and 4 are point referenced. The line data are such things as political districts, or construction segments, etc. and the point data is road and stream crossings, etc.

I feel certain that someone must have paved the way in this area before. I am not the first person mapping multiple pages and multiple variables.

With data driven pages, in order to display some variable data on the page, you have to select one of the data driven page attributes. So I am thinking this route data has to be incorporated into my data driven page centers table.

I understand how routes work when drawn on a single map, but am not sure how to make the leap to data driven pages with linear referencing and dynamic segmentation, or how to abstract it outside the map, yet retain the linear horizontal reference of the map. (I have 60 pages to map) How do I incorporate these routes and their linear referenced data into a data driven page?

I am running ArcMap 10.2.

Comment: The term you want to search is "alignment sheet." I know there are numerous commercial solutions out there, there may be some free ones as well.

Comment: I work for a company that produces alignment sheets.  There are  definitely commercial solutions and they're not cheap.  I have not yet seen one that is free.  They can be quite complex to produce with lots of variables.  If you come up with a Data Driven Pages solution, let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solution to automate alignment sheet band-data on map with ArcMap 10.0 and Arcpy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21816/solution-to-automate-alignment-sheet-band-data-on-map-with-arcmap-10-0-and-arcpy)

Comment: Yes, thank you Jason and Fetzer. It is a form of customized alignment sheet. I browsed the term after you posted it. Unfortunately, we don't have the budget to purchase one, so I will have to develop something.

Answer (score 1):

1. Represent each route as 5 (accidents, lanes..) parallel horizontal lines (unprojected) with length= actual road length. Space vertically these schematic lines just enough to place labels if any. Apply linear referencing tables to create colours (labels) to these straight lines.
2. Tricky part. Find where your actual pages intersect route, you'll need a distance from route start. Use these FromChainage and ToChainage to define long and narrow quasi pages for schematic lines.
3. You can use second data frame to show schematics and move through relevant quasi pages as you move through real ones. I'd suggest using picture element in layout, pointing to true pages attachments.

To produce attachments I'd use separate mxd for schematic lines and quasi pages to export lines to graphic (png ?) and attach them to true pages. Consider using coding to quickly update and re-attach all the graphics. With that number of pages the script needed, when you'll eventually find very minor imperfection in graphics to fix.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I have exact station numbers for the start and end of each sheet. The link that Felix added above is closer to what I am doing, but this is a forestry/pipeline application. Part 1 issue is getting the data on the print out, not the actual map. My Point data can be mostly achieved with linear referenced labels, with one exception where one of the points has a bi-directional component with a length attached. Also, I am not sure if I understand part 3 of your post though.

Comment: I understand that you want a print that has 2 frames. Upper shows aerial with route polygon on the top. Lat-long coordinates. Lower shows different parameters of the route (1D coordinates system, 0 at route start). If this is correct, you can use 2 dataframes to move along the route. Instead of lower dataframe the picture element of layout can be used, with picture source = true page attachment. Attachments are to be created as graphics from your schematics points. I am using similar approach to show map of the route with long-section underneath.

Comment: No. I am doing a variant of an Alignment Sheet (I didn't know what it was called when I posted the original question as we call it by a different name). If you peruse the document in the link "Solution to automate alignment sheet band-data on map with ArcMap 10.0 and Arcpy" that Fetzer posted. I think it will give you a better idea. One data frame, with stations for linear distances of to/from locations (ie: from km 235+500 to 243+500). I am using data driven pages. So each page center has to have the 11 routes on it so I can print it on each of 60 map pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have been slowly making progress on this issue.

I have created routes and events and event layers.

I tried relating and joining the event tables to the data driven page center layer, but apparently you have to open the table, click on the related tables tab, and then select the particular related table. All of which is NOT available from the Insert Dynamic Text, data driven page attribute list.

Then I found this nugget of information that tells you how to do this sort of thing:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002z000000

Note that you have to have ObjectIDs in your event tables. The key paragraphs are the last two. So it is necessary to query the tables and sub-tables using the Insert Dynamic Text, data driven page display expression. This uses the display expression that is set up in the display tabs of the properties window for the particular field as its display expression.

I think using this method that you need to select the events somehow from the sub-table (events table) that fall in the range of the From/To stations in the data driven page. Although I am still not sure how you access the sub-table or display it in a geo-reference form. This does however give you access to scripting in VB or python and also hyperlinks, which I have not figured out how to do yet. I will keep you posted on my progress. -